# Keep getting No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, ant, android-studio

I am trying to install my app on the emulator. According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html), I  should do this:

```
ant debug
adb install bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk
```

But that `ant debug` is giving me this error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

I read some threads and did what they suggested. i.e.:

```
1. I checked that Android Support Repository is installed in SDK Manager.
2. Included the following in my build.gradle file:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

still get the same error.

How can I fix it?

UPDATE:

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project in android studio

Comment: Can you build via command line? `gradlew build`? Post your `styles.xml`.

Comment: @X7S cleaning and rebuilding did not help

Comment: @JaredBurrows, I posted my styles file

Comment: Does this error come up when you build or when you put your cursor over the text? Have you tried building from command line?

Comment: @JaredBurrows, no error on build, it is green and does not say anything on hover. I tried `gradlew build` but it said `command not found`. I started learning Android today and installed Android studio today. After downloading, I started it like `sudo ../studio.sh` and did standrand installation. Everything got installed in `root` folder. Could it be the reason?

Comment: What is "green"? `gradlew` should be in your project's folder. I would not run Android Studio with `sudo`. You should not and should not have to install anything in the root folder.

Comment: I installed that way because it would not install. It kept giving me `Cannot install some kind of file` error. `Green` is colod :-D . I will try to install it without sudo and try again